# Improving performance of syntax match regular expression

Tags: vim

I'm improving the Verilog syntax by adding support for automatic folding.
Initially I was doing the following:

`syn region  verilogFold start="\<task\>" end="\<endtask\>" transparent keepend fold`

But because `task` is also used as a `syntax keyword`, no folds are detected.
So, to avoid matching the `task` keyword I am now using:

`syn region  verilogFold start="\(^\s*task\)\@<=\s\+\w\+" end="\<endtask\>" transparent keepend fold`

Unfortunately this results in a huge increase on the time vim takes to process each file.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this expression could be improved to result in better performance?

Comment: Take a look at using `\zs`, `:h /\zs`. The docs mention using `\zs` for speed in the positive look-behind atom documentation, `:h /\@<=`.

Comment: It was a good idea and is in fact faster. But apparently it does not circumvent the fact that `task` is part of a `syntax keyword` group, as no fold is detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the *positive lookbehind* can be slow. In recent Vim 7.4 versions, you can limit the search to 4 bytes (via `\@4<=`), but I think in this case, it's better to remove the separate keyword definitions and instead color the region start and end via `matchgroup`:

```
syn region verilogFold matchgroup=verilogStatement start="\<task\>" end="\<endtask\>" transparent keepend fold
```

If this doesn't work, try removing the `transparent` attribute; I'm not sure whether that applies to `matchgroup`, but I guess not.

Comment: Just to confirm if I understood the solution correctly: this requires that I remove `task` and `endtask` from verilogStatement keyword list. I was trying to expand the existing `syntax/verilog.vim` without modifying it directly by reading it inside my syntax file. Is it possible to remove an individual keyword from a group?

Comment: Using `matchgroup` makes it worth having to copy all old `verilogStatement` keywords back to my syntax file, since now it has the correct highlight. It's a pity that there's nothing like `-=` for syntax keywords though.